# libxml2-p25 on OS X 10.5 needs sudo?

Tags: python, macos, libxml2

When trying to use `libxml2` as myself I get an error saying the package cannot be found. If I run as as super user I am able to import fine.

I have installed `python25` and all `libxml2` and `libxml2-py25` related libraries via fink and own the entire path including the library. Any ideas why I'd still need to sudo?

Answer (score 3):

Check your path by running:

```
'echo $PATH'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect the permissions on the library. Can you do a strace or similar to find out the filenames it's looking for, and then check the permissions on them?

Answer (score 0):

The `PATH` environment variable was the mistake.